# Why is now() and now()::timestamp in Postgres so "wrong" for CET and CEST timezones?

Tags: postgresql

I try to understand some query examples using `TIMESTAMP WITH TIMEZONE` in **Postgres**.

Given are some queries that convert the `now`-result into TimeStamp for timezones "CET" and "CEST". "CEST" is 1 hour ahead of CET (summer time)

**Examples:**

```sql
SELECT 1, now()
UNION
SELECT 2, now()::timestamp
UNION
SELECT 3, now() AT TIME ZONE 'CET'
UNION
SELECT 4, now()::timestamp AT TIME ZONE 'CET'
UNION
SELECT 5, now() AT TIME ZONE 'CEST'
UNION
SELECT 6, now()::timestamp AT TIME ZONE 'CEST'
;
```

**Results:**

```
    1, 2023-09-10 17:07:10.524389 +00:00
    2, 2023-09-10 17:07:10.524389 +00:00
    3, 2023-09-10 18:07:10.524389 +00:00
    4, 2023-09-10 16:07:10.524389 +00:00
    5, 2023-09-10 19:07:10.524389 +00:00
    6, 2023-09-10 15:07:10.524389 +00:00
```

So, the difference between

```
SELECT 5, now() AT TIME ZONE 'CEST'
```

… and:

```
SELECT 6, now()::timestamp AT TIME ZONE 'CEST'
```

… is 4 hours. Why?

The difference between

```
SELECT 3, now() AT TIME ZONE 'CET'
```

… and:

```
SELECT 4, now()::timestamp AT TIME ZONE 'CET'
```

… is 2 hours. I don't understand that either.

The current timezone of my Postgres-Container is UTC:

```
SELECT current_setting('TIMEZONE');

> UTC
```

Can someone explain please?

Comment: The first complication is that a column can only have one type, so your use of UNION means all the outputs, even the ones that *should* be timestamp, have been coerced back into timestamptz.

Comment: See [AT TIME ZONE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-ZONECONVERT): *timestamp without time zone AT TIME ZONE zone → timestamp with time zone Converts given time stamp without time zone to time stamp with time zone, assuming the given value is in the named time zone.* Then as @jjanes mentions you are coercing everything back to `timestamptz` and getting a double timestamp conversion.

Comment: `AT TIME ZONE` on a `timestamp` does the opposite of `AT TIME ZONE` on a `timestamp with time zone`. You are running different queries, that's why you get a different result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### tl;dr

- Avoid `UNION` here. Your mix of `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`  and `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE` types results in implicit casting from the second to the first because of `UNION`.
- You are using the wrong type, `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE`, where you should be using only `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`.
- Invoking `AT TIME ZONE` flips back and forth between `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` and `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE` types.
- You are using pseudo time zones (`CET`/`CEST`) that only indicate whether Daylight Saving Time is in effect or not. Any of several real time zones could be intended by those pseudo-zones.
- The *psql* console app is unfortunately applying a default time zone to `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` values that are actually always in UTC (have an offset of zero).

### Wrong type: `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE`

You are using the wrong data type. `TIMESTAMP` is an abbreviation for `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE` per the SQL standard.

That type has no concept of time zone or offset-from-UTC. So it cannot represent a moment, a specific point on the timeline. That type represents merely an ambiguous date with time-of-day, nothing more. If you tell me "noon on January 23, 2024", how do I know if you mean noon in Tokyo, noon in Toulouse, or noon in Toledo Ohio — three very different moments, several hours apart.

See the [Postgres documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html).

### Correct type: `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`

You should be using the other type,  `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`. This type *does* have the concept of offset, always storing a submitted value in UTC (an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds from the temporal meridian of UTC).

Any offset or zone information accompanying a submitted value is used to adjust to UTC and then discarded.

If you want to retain information about that original zone, you’ll need to record that as text in a second column.

You may abbreviate `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` as `TIMESTAMPTZ`, as a Postgres-specific feature. Personally, I always spell out both types with their full name to avoid confusion from misreading.

Be aware that this store-in-UTC behavior is the policy choice of the Postgres team. Some other database engines work the same way; others do not. Always study the documentation. The SQL standard is woefully lacking in specifying behavior of date-time handling.

### Beware of tools

Unfortunately, some database access tools and middleware may choose to ⚠️ inject some default time zone onto the UTC value retrieved from Postgres. While well-intentioned, this anti-feature creates the false illusion of that zone having been stored. The *pgAdmin* app is one such tool.

I would argue that a data access tool should always “tell the truth”, and not fiddle with retrieval results. But those tool creators did not ask me    .

So understand that in Postgres: Any and all `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` values were stored with an offset of zero, and were retrieved with an offset of zero. Any other zone or offset you see was overlaid by a meddlesome tool.

### Real time zones

`CET` and `CEST` are not real time zones.

Such pseudo-zones are to be used only in presentation to the user, never in data storage or data exchange.

[Real time zones](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) have a name in the format of `Continent/Region`. A few examples:

- `Europe/Paris`
- `Europe/Berlin`
- `Europe/Stockholm`
- `Europe/Warsaw`

### Your examples

Let's look at your sample code.

```sql
SELECT 1, now()
UNION
SELECT 2, now()::timestamp
UNION
SELECT 3, now() AT TIME ZONE 'CET'
UNION
SELECT 4, now()::timestamp AT TIME ZONE 'CET'
UNION
SELECT 5, now() AT TIME ZONE 'CEST'
UNION
SELECT 6, now()::timestamp AT TIME ZONE 'CEST'
;
```

Per the documentation for Postres 15.4 [date-time functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/functions-datetime.html) and [date-time types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/datatype-datetime.html)…

The first one, `now()` returns a `timestamp with time zone` value. We can try it by setting the session to an offset of zero, to UTC.

```sql
set timezone='UTC' ;
```

Verify with:

```sql
show timezone ;
```

Call the `now` function.

```
             now              
------------------------------
 2023-09-11 01:13:03.64721+00
(1 row)
```

We see an offset of `+00`, meaning an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds from UTC. So this is the time-of-day seen on the [Shepherd Gate Clock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shepherd_Gate_Clock) at the [Royal Observatory, Greenwich](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Royal_Observatory,_Greenwich) (well, within a second or so, we'll not get into GMT versus UTC here, irrelevant for practical business contexts).

Set the default time zone of our session to Berlin time.

```sql
set timezone='Europe/Berlin' ;
```

And `SELECT now() ;`.

```
2023-09-11 03:19:46.171143+02
```

We see the hour is two hours ahead, `03` versus the `01` seen above. This accords with the `+02`. These two results represent the same moment, the same point on the timeline (or would have, if I'd typed faster). Their wall-clock time differs, as it would for someone in Iceland phoning someone in Berlin, and both look up simultaneously at their respective clock on the wall — one person sees 1 AM, the other person sees 3 AM.

**BEWARE:** We now see that the *psql* has the anti-feature of applying a default time zone while generating the text to display on the console. The value in Postgres, the `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE`, is always in UTC. So we cannot exactly trust the output of *psql* in the sense that what the tool shows us is *not* exactly what the database engine produces.

In contrast, if you retrieve this value in Java via JDBC with a call like `myResultSet.getObject( … , OffsetDateTime.class )`, you will *always* get a value with an offset of zero.

Your next line:

```sql
SELECT 2, now()::timestamp
```

… used the wrong type, `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE`. You are discarding valuable information, the offset-from-UTC with nothing gained in return. That line should have been:

```sql
SELECT 2, now()::TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE
```

But this is silly, as you already had a `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE` value in hand. The cast is meaningless, adding no value.

Your third line:

```sql
SELECT 3, now() AT TIME ZONE 'CET'
```

… uses a pseudo time zone. That should have used a real time zone name. Something like this:

```sql
SELECT 3, now() AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Berlin'
```

But you have to be careful with the [`AT TIME ZONE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-ZONECONVERT) operator. The operator flips the type of the input back and forth between `timestamp with time zone` and `timestamp without time zone` types:

- If you operate on a `timestamp without time zone` value, you get back a `timestamp with time zone` value.
- And vice versa, operating on a `timestamp with time zone` returns a `timestamp without time zone`.

While adding or stripping the offset, an adjustment is made to the time & date per the time zone you specify.

So this line:

```sql
SELECT now() AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Berlin' ;
```

… gives you the date & time as seen in the Berlin region, without regard to the default time zone of our database session.

So in our example scenario of 1 AM UTC, the line above will always return the text below with a 3 AM time-of-day, regardless of whether the default time zone is UTC, Europe/Berlin, or Asia/Tokyo.

```
         timezone          
---------------------------
 2023-09-11 03:39:19.67042
(1 row)
```

But notice in that line above that we have lost our offset indication. That is because we called `AT TIME ZONE` to operate on a `timestamp with time zone`, and we got back a `timestamp without time zone`, having lost our offset content after making the date-time adjustment.

Your fourth line, `SELECT 4, now()::timestamp AT TIME ZONE 'CET'` repeats two of the mistakes of your earlier lines: (a) casting a `timestamp with time zone` into a `timestamp without time zone` thereby losing the offset info, and (b) using a pseudo time zone. So we can delete this line, as it does not further our understanding.

Your fifth line, `SELECT 5, now() AT TIME ZONE 'CEST'`, uses a different pseudo time zone, `CEST` versus `CET`. The difference between these is that the `S` means to indicate "Summer Time", that is, that [Daylight Saving Time (DST)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) is being observed. This is one of the problems with these pseudo-zones: people often confuse the DST versus non-DST counterparts and use the wrong one. Again, we should not be using these pseudo-zones in our programming. So we can drop this line of yours.

Your sixth line, `SELECT 6, now()::timestamp AT TIME ZONE 'CEST'`, can also be ignored. Again, this line makes an inappropriate cast, and inappropriately uses pseudo-zones.

By using real time zone names, such as `Europe/Berlin`, rather than pseudo-zones such as `CET`/`CEST`,  we let the software determine if DST is in effect at our given moment. Postgres has its own embedded copy of [*tzdata*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database). As long as that file is up-to-date, then we can rely on Postgres to determine DST or not for a particular date & time in `Europe/Berlin`.

So we can boil down your example code to a modified version of the only useful/sensible lines in your example code, the first and third lines:

```sql
SET timezone='UTC' 
;
SELECT 1 AS RowNo , now() 
;
SELECT 3 as RowNo, now() AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Berlin' 
;
```

Result:

```
SET
 rowno |              now              
-------+-------------------------------
     1 | 2023-09-11 02:05:53.188829+00
(1 row)

 rowno |          timezone          
-------+----------------------------
     3 | 2023-09-11 04:05:53.189836
(1 row)
```

#### Implicit casting of mixed types produced by `UNION`

We another issue to consider, raised in a [Comment by jjanes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77077167/why-is-now-and-nowtimestamp-in-postgres-so-wrong-for-cet-and-cest-timezo/77077217#comment135878688_77077167).  Your **use of UNION** to combine the SELECT queries **alters the results**.

Notice how, in the results shown directly above, # 3 has no offset indicator. This means the result is a `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE` value. But # 1 *does* have an offset indicator, which means that item is a `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` value. So we have two different separate `SELECT` statements whose results are of different data types.

Let's try the approach seen in the Question with `UNION`. We replace the semicolon with a `UNION`.

```sql
SET timezone='UTC' 
;
SELECT 1 AS RowNo , now() 
UNION
SELECT 3 as RowNo, now() AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Berlin' 
;
```

Whoa! These results do not match the results above. Here we see an offset indicator on *both* # 1 and # 3. So now # 3 is a `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` value. Why? The type of a column must be the same across rows. How? Postgres implicitly cast the `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE` value into a  `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` value, applying an offset where we had none in the previous example.

```
SET
 rowno |              now              
-------+-------------------------------
     1 | 2023-09-11 02:10:13.934363+00
     3 | 2023-09-11 04:10:13.934363+00
(2 rows)
```

The key to understand here is that the date-time functions return date-time values, **not mere strings**. (The *psql* app then generates text from these typed values for display.)

To fix the mixing of types problem, Postgres tries to be helpful by casting. So, in the end, the `UNION` version of this code produces semantically different results than the non-`UNION` version.

This means the Question's code example is even less useful for trying to learn about Postgres' date-time handling. For our studies, we must keep those example statements separate, without `UNION`.

---

By the way, time zone versus offset-from-UTC:

- **An offset** is merely a number of hours-minutes-seconds ahead of, or behind, the temporal meridian of UTC.
- **A time zone** is much more. A time zone is a named history of the past, present, and future changes to the offset used by the people of a particular region as decided by their politicians.

Comment: "*The pgAdmin app injects some default time zone*" - do you have a reference for that? I've heard of (and seen) other tools doing that, but in my experience pgAdmin4 does not.

Comment: Wow! What an epic answer!

Comment: I did not say thank you for this excellent answer. Here we go: THANK YOU SO MUCH! It helped me a lot!